# Gensim distributed Word2Vec & Doc2Vec

Tags: gensim, word2vec, distributed, doc2vec

I would like to implement a distributed Topic Modeling Pipeline based on Gensim. Unfortunately, Gensim only supports distributed LSA and LDA. I read that Word2Vec and Doc2Vec tend to have better results than LSA and LDA. However, I also read about pretrained Word2Vec and Doc2Vec models. Is there a way to use Word2Vec or Doc2Vec in a distributed manner?

Answer (score 0):

Gensim include no support for distributed `Word2Vec` or `Doc2Vec`.

But also, many people who think they need distributed versions of these algorithms can actually achieve their goals on a single beefy machine.

Further, you can probably confirm or deny whether `Word2Vec` or `Doc2Vec` work better on your specific data/goals, rather than trusting some other claims you've read, via some single-machines tests long before concerning yourself with scaling/distribution issues.